# Force connection to a server through 10G interface adapter, en4 instead of en0, on macOS

Tags: networking, command-line, mac

I have two macs (iMac and Mac mini server with attached RAID storage) that both use a 1GB LAN 192.168.10.x/255.255.255.0 for internet connection using the built in ethernet ports. They are attached to a 1G switch and router.

I now have two 10G Thunderbolt adapters and a cat6 cable and have connected these two macs for file transfers. The connection works when I turn off every other service, however the connection will default back to the 1G LAN even with the 10G listed as first in Service Order.

I need to have both the 1G and 10G active at the same time. How can I accomplish this?

I have followed Apple's suggestion of listing them in the order I want them prioritized and it doesn't seem to have an effect.

```
networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
(1) Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1
(Hardware Port: Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1, Device: en4)

(2) Ethernet
(Hardware Port: Ethernet, Device: en0)

(3) Wi-Fi
(Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: en1)
```

```
route get default | grep interface
  interface: en0
```

---

I have played around with `networksetup` and `route` and done some googlin', but don't really have a grasp on it.

### Mac mini

**Thunderbolt 10G adapter settings**

Virtual Interface "Thunderbolt Bridge" 
including "Thunderbolt 1" and "Thunderbolt 2" interfaces

Service "Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1" 
Static
192.168.5.1
255.255.255.0
mac address of adapter: 00:24:27:09:09:87

As soon as I set up the adapters I see these entries in the table:

```
netstat -nr
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
...
192.168.5          link#11            UCS               en4      !
192.168.5.1/32     link#11            UCS               en4      !
192.168.5.1        0:24:27:9:9:87     UHLWIi            lo0       
192.168.5.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI            en4      !
...
```

If I remove every service but "thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1" and connect to the Mac Mini with screen sharing using 192.168.5.1

```
192.168.5          link#11            UCS               en4      !
192.168.5.1/32     link#11            UCS               en4      !
192.168.5.1        0:24:27:9:9:87     UHLWIi            lo0       
192.168.5.2        0:24:27:9:9:85     UHLWIi            en4   1059
192.168.5.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI            en4      !
```

### iMac

**Thunderbolt 10G adapter settings**

Virtual Interface "Thunderbolt Bridge" 
including "Thunderbolt 1" and "Thunderbolt 2" interfaces

Service "Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1" 
Static
192.168.5.2
255.255.255.0
mac address of adapter: 00:24:27:09:09:85

I see these entries in the table:

```
netstat -nr
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
...
192.168.5          link#5             UCS               en4      !
192.168.5.1        0:24:27:9:9:87     UHLWIi            en4   1181
192.168.5.2/32     link#5             UCS               en4      !
...
```

Comment: What file transfer software? Are you telling it to connect by IP address, or are you just picking from a list or using a hostname? Did you try using the link-local IPv6 address, specifying the correct interface scope (%en4)? (BTW, if the two Macs happen to be within 2 meters of each other, you should get much better performance if you connect them via direct Thunderbolt cable instead of 10G Ethernet).

Comment: @Spiff The two Macs are in different rooms. I connect using Screen Sharing since the Mac mini is headless. When I connect using Screen Sharing I am using the regular LAN 192.168.10.x and mounting the server's HDDs as SMB shares.

Comment: But how do you establish the SMB connection? Are you specifying the 10G interface's 192.168.5.x address?

Comment: @Spiff Thank you! This was it, I was connecting first through the "Connect to Server" which was choosing the 192.168.10.x network without my knowledge, even though en0 was deprioritized. In fact one of the network shares keeps connecting via 192.168.10.x and 192.168.5.x. I am not sure how to stop it from automatically connecting on that IP.

Comment: I think you'll need to just type in an IP address each time (or a URL like smb://192.168.5.2/ ). Prioritizing the services only sets which interface is used to reach non-local subnets. It's not about preferring one local subnet over another.

Comment: I have the server's drives mounted. In "Locations" on the sidebar it doesn't show as "Mac Mini" it shows as its IP address, and the drives show as directories in it's Finder window with kind "Sharepoint" not as Volumes. Although they are shown as Volumes on the Desktop. Can I do anything with `fstab` to change this?